# How do I fix this syntax error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

The code is:

```
  function roundAmount(theDecimal) { 
    var s = "" + Math.round(theDecimal * 100) / 100 
    var i = s.indexOf('.') 
    if (i < 0) { 
        return s + ".00" 
    } 
    var t = s.substring(0, i + 1) + s.substring(i + 1, i + 3) 
    if (i + 2 == s.length)     
        t += "0" 
    return t 
  }
```

The line with the error:

```
if (i < 0) return s + ".00"
```

The error is:

```
error: expected (;)
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: oh by the way the laguage is java script thanks

Comment: a semi-colon missing shouldn't matter in javascript

Comment: that line is fine.  Error must be somewhere else.  I think it might be one line above perhaps.  Need to see more code...

Comment: Is this the type of question that we should just answer by fixing the question? i.e. "My problem was that I wrote {this}, but I really should have written {that}" where {this} is his original stuff and {that} is the "correct" answer.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 

 
function roundAmount(theDecimal) {
var s = "" + Math.round(theDecimal * 100) / 100
var i = s.indexOf('.')
if (i < 0) 
 {
    return s + ".00"
  }
var t = s.substring(0, i + 1) + s.substring(i + 1, i + 3)
if (i + 2 == s.length) t += "0"
return t
}
hope that helps it still come up with the error when i put the semi colon in

Comment: to Erich

i know what it's saying the problem is but thats not actually the problem it's got to be somewhere else thats why i added more code i just need this fixed asap and will be much apprecieted when it is

Comment: I know. Maybe not in this case. But I mean is that plenty of times, there are "easy" questions that can people can answer by editing the question. In a way, it goes against the "rep" concept, but the overall point is to help people answer their questions.  Obviously, we needed more info to fix your problem in this case. I'm sure SO will come to your rescue soon.

Comment: have you tried adding all the terminating semicolons explicitly? is there a line number associated with the error? what made you believe it was that one specific line?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
function roundAmount(theDecimal) {
var s = "" + Math.round(theDecimal * 100) / 100
var i = s.indexOf('.');
if (i < 0) ;
 {
    return s + ".00";
  }
var t = s.substring(0, i + 1) + s.substring(i + 1, i + 3);
if (i + 2 == s.length) t += "0";
return t;
}
function reCalc() {
if (document.getElementById("hours").value > 24){
alert("24 hours a day is all we have!")
return false
}
          </script> the code looks fine to me but im not thaat strong a coder so just let me know if you see anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About your script:**

The problem in the script above is that last if statement which does some operations followed by a return. You need a semi-colon after the operation.

In the future, as good practice, make sure to put a semi-colon after **every** valid statement. That way this won't bother you.

Think of each line as a thought, and curly braces as ways to "group" and "relate" thoughts together.

The below is a full thought that says "give me a variable "i" and give it the value 1 + 2;

```
var i = 1 + 2;
```

The below is a full thought about a condition that says "If i is 3 then add 1 to i". The thought "add 1 to i" is its own thought, so  it needs a semicolon. Since the curlybraces for the IF statement are special in that they don't need a semi-colon after their "full thought" as long as you put a "block" (which is what curlybraces really make) after it, to enclose the thought.

This means the following is valid:

```
if( i == 3 ) {
    i = i + 1;
}
```

The following is **not** valid because the semi-colon after the if ends the "thought" before the if knows what to do if i equals 3:

```
if( i == 3 ) ; {
    i = i + 1;
}
```

For a basic JavaScript tutorial, check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp).

**"There must be a better way?"**

Any time you find yourself doing a lot of string operations on decmials, it's a good idea to ask yourself "is there a better way to do this?".

It looks like you're writing a function to round a number to the nearest hundredths while displaying two decimal points. There's a much easier way to do this. You can just round to the nearest hundredths and have javascript output the fixed point number.

Example:

```
function roundAmount( theDecimal ) {
    //first round to the nearest hundredth
    //then return the value with two decimal places as a string
    return theDecimal.toFixed( 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (i < 0) return s + ".00";
```

Note the `;` at the end of the statement.  Personally, I prefer surrounding almost all my `if`s in `{}` such as

```
if (i < 0) 
{
    return s + ".00";
}
```

Which helps in debugging and stepping though code.

Answer (score 4):

Add a semicolon at the end of the line! Like this:

```
if (i < 0) return s + ".00";
```

Answer (score 4):

It's expecting a semicolon, so add a semicolon.

```
if (i < 0) 
  return s + ".00";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with the code you posted in the earlier comments, but may I suggest always adding a semi-colon to the end of your statements.  Though they are not required, it usually makes it easier to debug problems such as these.